# Listing time every second as a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

first time here as I've finally started to learn programming. Anyway, I'm just trying to print the time in nanoseconds every second here, and I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true;
do
 date=(date +%N) ;
 echo $date ;
 sleep  1 ;
done
```

Now, that simply yields a string of date's, which isn't what I want. What is wrong? My learning has been rather messy, so I hope you'll excuse me for this if it's really simple. Also, I did manage to fine this, that worked on the prompt:

```
while true ; do date +%N ; sleep 1 ; done
```

But that obviously doesn't work as a script?

Edit, if anyone sees this: Ahh, this does indeed fix my error. I note you didn't add a ; Is that because I only defined a variable? Also, could you explain what the $ does? I thought it was for calling variables. And I see that the above line will indeed work as a script; I had expected the output of date to not be put on the screen.

Comment: You forgot the question.

Comment: "But that obviously doesn't work as a script."  why not?

Comment: Actually, none of the semicolons in your script are needed -- they're only needed when you put two commands on the same line.  As for the `$`, it does a bunch of different things depending on what follows it: `$var` and `${var}` expand a variable, `$(command)` runs a command and substitutes its output, and (in bash only) `$((expr))` evaluates a mathematical expression.

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
date=(date +%N) ;
```

to

```
date=$(date +%N)
```

Answer (score 2):

This version should work

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
 date=$(date +"%N")
 echo Current date is $date
 sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose your command between "`" (Backtick) too.
For example:

```
date=`date +%N`
```

Regards

Comment: Avoid backticks! use `$(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner using shell commands

```
while [ 1 ] ; do echo -en "$(date +%T)\r" ; sleep 1; done
```

exit using CTRL+C